# Single-Expression Member Function Pointers

Tags: c++, c++20

The standard way to represent a pointer to a member function for a specific instance of a class is to use a pointer to the instance and a pointer to the member function:

```
void Execute(Foo* inst, void (Foo::*func)(int), int x) {
  (inst->*func)(x);
}
...
Execute(foo, &Foo::Bar, 42);
```

**Is there any way to define Execute such that the function pointer is represented as a single expression?**

For example:

```
void Execute(SomeType v, int x) {
  (v.inst->*v.func)(x);
}
...
Execute(foo->Bar, 42);
```

My main problem is that in my specific case, `Foo` is nested under a long and unstable chain of namespaces, so an actual invocation using the standard syntax looks more like `Execute(foo, &hello::darkness::my::old::friend::Foo::Bar, 42)`. I almost always have a local `foo` instance however, from which I can refer to the much simpler `foo->Bar(42)`. I need to do some extra bookkeeping though, which is why I need to wrap the call in something like `Execute`. `using` directives and namespace aliases are not an option unfortunately.

Comment: As _just_ a member pointer, no. But you can easily write a type that binds member functions

Comment: @Human-Compiler Right, but then I can't actually invoke it on a specific instance. It also still requires spelling out the whole namespace. Or are you saying it's possible to translate `foo->Bar` into `&hello::darkness...::Foo::Bar`?

Comment: Reading this again, I might have misunderstood the question. If you're looking to avoid typing the full name of the type when trying to access the member pointer, you're either going to need a `using` _alias_ to try to shorten it, or at best use `&decltype(foo)::Bar` to avoid the fully qualified name

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible, but would you be happy with something like `Execute(foo, Bar, 42);`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler I figured I could use some `decltype` magic, but it ends up needing to look like `&std::remove_reference<decltype(*foo)>::type::Bar` which is still pretty gross. Is there a way to hide that gunk in the implementation (without using macros)?

Comment: @cigien Yes that would be fine as well, but AFAIK there's no way to accomplish that without macros, since `Bar` by itself isn't even a valid token in that scope.

Comment: Indeed. I was just shooting from the hip ;) I don't think what you want is possible, but it's a good question.

Comment: "*`using` directives and namespace aliases are not an option unfortunately*" - why?  They seem very well-suited for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to define Execute such that the function pointer is represented as a single expression?

Yes.  Change the function to use `std::function` or a *callable* template parameter, eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

void Execute(std::function<void(int)> v, int x)
{
    v(x);
}
```

```cpp
template<typename Callable>
void Execute(Callable v, int x)
{
    v(x);
}
```

And then you can use `std::bind()` or a lambda for the input expression, eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;
using FooType = std::remove_reference<decltype(*foo)>::type;

Execute(std::bind(&FooType::Bar, foo, _1), 42);
// or, in C++20 and later:
Execute(std::bind_front(&FooType::Bar, foo), 42);
```

```cpp
Execute([=](int x){ foo->Bar(x); }, 42);
```

---

Also, just to mention that in C++Builder specifically, there is a `__closure` extension that allows calling member methods without having to qualify the class type at all, eg:

```cpp
typedef void (__closure *TExecuteCallable)(int);

void Execute(TExecuteCallable v, int x)
{
    v(x);
}

...

Execute(foo->Bar, 42);
// or
Execute(&(foo->Bar), 42);
```

Comment: Small note: C++20 has `std::bind_front`, which is preferable to the heavyweight tool that is `std::bind`: `std::bind_front(&FooType::Bar, foo)`

Comment: Although this answers the question as written by the title, this doesn't appear to solve the real problem detailed in the rest of the post and the comments -- which appears to be not wanting to fully qualify the type-name when getting the member function pointer.

Comment: @Human-Compiler really? The `FooType` alias with `decltype` doesn't address that? Or the fact that the lambda eliminates the need for that at all?

Comment: I think I must have misread your answer initially; no need to get defensive. I didn't catch that `FooType` was an alias, and I misread the lambda as still using member functions. My bad!

Comment: @chris added, thanks. Though, a lambda is usually preferable over *any* use of `std::bind...()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yep! The nice thing about `bind_front` is that it doesn't have complex requirements—it could be implemented as a lambda.